# Reports API to retrieve Admin Privilede Granting

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I am currently trying to retrieve user events that grant admin or delegate privileges to accounts under our domain. I guessed such event names called `GRANT_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE` and `GRANT_DELEGATED_ADMIN_PRIVILEGES` is the one: 
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/admin-user-events?authuser=1

So, I filled the form in https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-admin?authuser=1#get_account_events to generate a request like `GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/admin&eventName=GRANT_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE or GRANT_DELEGATED_ADMIN_PRIVILEGES`.

The result is 200 OK, but without any data in it (Of course, I actually granted Privilege to my coworker in last 2 months).

So, is it right to think `GRANT_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE` or `GRANT_DELEGATED_ADMIN_PRIVILEGES` is the event name I am looking for to audit granting activities? Or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to visit [Reports API: Admin Activity – Delegated Admin Event Names](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/admin-deladmin-events) which details the admin activity report `DELEGATED_ADMIN_SETTINGS` type's `eventName` parameters and properties. For more information, see also the [Activities: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list) method.

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I was looking for.